# Shape is not erased

Tags: c#, graphics, shapes

In here, When click delete button and clicked Yes, the shape should be deleted together with the row.
[image]

But this happens:

[image]
 I already added a picturebox refresh after the button events, but this still happens. But when I try to draw another image, the last image drawn wouldn't be erased as well until you draw another one.

Code:

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the Shape?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string type = (string)dgv_Layers.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
            int index = (int)dgv_Layers.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
            //MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
            if(type == "R" || type == "S")
            {
                draw._rectangles.RemoveAt(index-1);
                dgv_Layers.Rows.RemoveAt(index-1);
                counter--;
            }
            else if (type == "C" || type == "E")
            {
                draw._circles.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                dgv_Layers.Rows.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                counter--;
            }
            else if(type == "T")
            {
                draw._triangle.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                dgv_Layers.Rows.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                counter--;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Layers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dgv_Layers.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + 1;
            }

            pictureBox_Canvass.Refresh();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

**Drawing the Shape**

This is how I Draw:

> Shape Class

```
    public void DrawRectangle(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h,Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;

        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(c,stroke), points.X, points.Y,w,h);
    }
```

> Main Form

```
public void DrawRect()
    {
        rW = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        rH = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        rX = (s.center.X - (rW / 2));
        rY = (s.center.Y - (rH / 2));
        strokeRect = trackBar_Stroke.Value;
        rC = Color.Red;
    }

    private void pictureBox_Canvass_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      switch (buttons)
        {
            case Shape.ShapeType.rectangle:
                s.DrawRectangle(rC, strokeRect, new PointF(rX, rY), rW, rH, e.Graphics);
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.square:
                s.DrawSquare(sC, strokeSquare, new PointF(sX, sY), sW, sH, e.Graphics);
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.circle:
                s.DrawCircle(cC, strokeCircle, new PointF(cX, cY), cW, cH, e.Graphics);
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.ellipse:
                s.DrawEllipse(eC, strokeEllipse, new PointF(eX, eY), eW, eH, e.Graphics);
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.triangle:
                s.DrawTriangle(tC, strokeTriangle, t_Points, tX, tY, tW, e.Graphics);
                break;
        }
```

}

**How I draw all of them**

```
public void DrawAllShapes(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_rectangles.Count == 0 && _circles.Count == 0 && _triangle.Count == 0)
        {
            ClearCanvass(sender, e);
            ShowGrid(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Shape shape in _rectangles)
            {
                shape.DrawRectangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                shape.DrawSquare(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
            }
            foreach (Shape shape in _circles)
            {
                shape.DrawCircle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                shape.DrawEllipse(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
            }
            foreach (Shape shapes3 in _triangle)
            {
                shapes3.DrawTriangle(shapes3.color, shapes3.strokeThickness, shapes3.tPoints.ToArray(), shapes3.x, shapes3.y, shapes3.width, e.Graphics);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `draw._rectangles`? Can you show how you draw your shapes?

Comment: _rectangles is the list of all rectangles I've drawn. I updated the code to show my drawing process, but for rectangle only

Comment: Your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help! Report back if the issue doesn't get resolved by following the branch the code actually takes! (Btw, in this case I always prefer Invalidate over Refresh..) - Also: You do draw in the Paint event, right??

Comment: when I call pictureBox.Invalidate(); Some of controls doesn't show up. @TaW

Comment: Hm, that sounds rather suspicious. All from the same type? Any other common feature of the missing shapes? Also: What is `s` and: Isn't there a loop missing?

Comment: s is Shape s = new Shape();. Common features are width, height, stroke and location. What loop could be missing? @TaW

Comment: Well, depending on what you actually want I would have expected a loop over all the shapes to display from the Paint event. But that maybe quite wrong, of course. - Did you try the debugger? We can't see the values of index etc..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ARhw3HpHuwXda87Kf5qN4HJdYHTLtrNL 

this is the exe file of the software

Comment: @TaW I don't know how to use the debugger to know the problem.

Comment: @TaW https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jl-Ww_O2ihI3Z9u_93upyenI5t3SBXnU link for the whole project

Comment: I would set a breakpoint after the deletion messagebox and then follow step by step to see what happens. Learing to use the debugger is the single most important task any programmer has. Do not defer it, start right now!! (No need for perfection, btw. simply stepping through code, adding a watch will make all the difference..) - But, no, we don't follow links to foreign code here.

Comment: @TaW updated the code. I showed how I draw all shapes.

Comment: OK, sorry to be so persistent but it is necessary to understand the full logic. So where is `DrawAllShapes` called? I ought to be from the Paint event, no?

Comment: it's in called in the canvassPaint Method. It's fine, I need help

Comment: That `pictureBox_Canvass_Paint` isn't calling `DrawAllShapes`. Do you have more paint methods? Also, in `DrawAllShapes`, I don't see a reason for the `if/else`. When you refresh the control, you should always clear it first.

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks, I already solved this.

Comment: Then please post an answer and accept it or delete your question.